# MongoDB SELECT COUNT GROUP BY

Tags: mongodb, group-by, aggregation-framework

I am playing around with MongoDB trying to figure out how to do a simple

```
SELECT province, COUNT(*) FROM contest GROUP BY province
```

But I can't seem to figure it out using the aggregate function. I can do it using some really weird group syntax

```
db.user.group({
    "key": {
        "province": true
    },
    "initial": {
        "count": 0
    },
    "reduce": function(obj, prev) {
        if (true != null) if (true instanceof Array) prev.count += true.length;
        else prev.count++;
    }
});
```

But is there an easier/faster way using the aggregate function?

Answer (score 552, accepted):

This would be the easier way to do it using [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/):

```js
db.contest.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$province", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

Comment: I get an error message when I try that `"errmsg" : "exception: A pipeline stage specification object must contain exactly one field.",` ?

Comment: how do you group sort to it? I want to sort count by  -1

Comment: @FilipBartuzi there is an example in the documentation page, you'll have to add a sort operation to the pipeline, as `{ $sort: { count: -1 } }`

Comment: I got the same exception as @Steven and it was because I copy-pasted just line 2 and omitted the surrounding square brackets.

Comment: @Steven you will have to execute it properly use something like this
.aggregate(aggregate).exec();

Comment: The `$` is very important in these queries.

Answer (score 166):

I need some extra operation based on the result of aggregate function. Finally I've found some solution for aggregate function and the operation based on the result in MongoDB. I've a collection `Request` with field `request, source, status, requestDate`.

**Single Field Group By & Count:**

```
db.Request.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$source", count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

**Multiple Fields Group By & Count:**

```
db.Request.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:{source:"$source",status:"$status"}, count:{$sum:1}}}
])
```

**Multiple Fields Group By & Count with Sort using Field:**

```
db.Request.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:{source:"$source",status:"$status"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{"_id.source":1}}
])
```

**Multiple Fields Group By & Count with Sort using Count:**

```
db.Request.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:{source:"$source",status:"$status"}, count:{$sum:1}}},
    {$sort:{"count":-1}}
])
```

Comment: can you explain {_id:{source:"$source",status:"$status"} this?

Comment: Basically, the field "_id" is a unique identifier for each document. The field accepts an expression. You can define the value of the field by combining multiple fields based on your grouping criteria. You will find more details about the field in the link: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

Answer (score 74):

If you need multiple columns to group by, follow this model. Here I am conducting a count by `status` and `type`:

```
  db.BusinessProcess.aggregate({
    "$group": {
        _id: {
            status: "$status",
            type: "$type"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        }
    }
   })
```

Comment: _id represents a default param for encapsulating multiple fields?

Comment: @RoyiNamir, please take a look at the link. You may find your information there. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group

Answer (score 56):

Starting in MongoDB 3.4, you can use the `$sortByCount` aggregation.

> Groups incoming documents based on the value of a specified expression, then computes the count of documents in each distinct group.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sortByCount/

For example:

```
db.contest.aggregate([
    { $sortByCount: "$province" }
]);
```

Comment: Probably worth noting here that `$sortByCount` is actually a "pseudo operator" like several more aggregation stage operators introduced from MongoDB 3.4. All they really do is **expand** into their respective aggregation stages. In this case a `$group` with `$sum: 1` as shown in existing answers and an additional `$sort`  stage. They offer no advantage other than *"typing less code"*, which may or may not be more descriptive ( if you're into that sort of thing ). IMHO, distinct `$group` and `$sort` stages in the code are far more descriptive and indeed more flexible.

Answer (score 28):

Additionally if you need to restrict the grouping you can use:

```
db.events.aggregate( 
    {$match: {province: "ON"}},
    {$group: {_id: "$date", number: {$sum: 1}}}  
)
```

Answer (score 11):

This type of query worked for me:

```
 db.events.aggregate({$group: {_id : "$date", number:  { $sum : 1} }} )
```

See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/aggregation-with-user-preference-data/

Answer (score 6):

Starting in `Mongo 5.0`, we can also use [`{ $count: { } }`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.0/reference/operator/aggregation/count-accum/#mongodb-group-grp.-count)  as an alias for `{ $sum : 1 }`:

```
// { "province" : "Champagne-Ardenne" }
// { "province" : "Champagne-Ardenne" }
// { "province" : "Haute-Normandie"   }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: { _id: "$province", count: { $count: {} } } }
])
// { "_id" : "Champagne-Ardenne", "count" : 2 }
// { "_id" : "Haute-Normandie",   "count" : 1 }
```

Answer (score 5):

```
    db.contest.aggregate([
        { $match:{.....May be some match criteria...}},
        { $project: {"province":1,_id:0}},
        { $sortByCount: "$province" }
    ],{allowDiskUse:true});
```

MongoDB have 32 MB limitation of sorting operation on memory, use allowDiskUse : true this option, when you expose this query upfront of millions of data, it will sort at disk level not in memory. MongoDB aggregation pipeline has 100MB limitation, so use $project to reduce the data flowing to next pipeline.
If you are using small data then no need to use allowDiskUse option.

Answer (score -1):

Mongo shell command that worked for me:

```
db.getCollection(<collection_name>).aggregate([{"$match": {'<key>': '<value to match>'}}, {"$group": {'_id': {'<group_by_attribute>': "$group_by_attribute"}}}])
```