# In Spring boot Mongodb find group by count by using Aggregation framework

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, aggregation

Hi a am try to do rest api in spring boot with mongodb to find group by count the input data look like. please share any logic, code, example link. 
guys i am expecting spring boot logic. how mongodb aggregation framework integrating.

```
{
    "_id" : "PRODUCT_01",
    "productname" : "product1",
    "value" : "codesoft"
},
{
    "_id" : "PRODUCT_01",
    "productname" : "product2",
    "value" : "codesoft"
},

{
    "_id" : "PRODUCT_01",
    "productname" : "product1",
    "value" : "codesoft"
}
```

expected output 
{
product1 : 2,
product2 : 1
}
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try on your own ? where is your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB SELECT COUNT GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by)

Comment: Amit i have create but it is not proper solution that's why i have not share..

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
 db.testColln.aggregate(
{ 
$group : {_id : "$productname", total : { $sum : 1 }}
}
 );
```

for Spring Boot

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
        group("productname").count().as("total")
        project("productname").and("total"),

    );
AggregationResults<Product> groupResults 
        = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, Product.class,Result.class);
    List<Result> result = groupResults.getMappedResults();

 public class Result {

     private String productname;

      private long total;

   }
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution? Which parts are relevant, and why do you think they solve the problem?

Comment: gaurav thanx for this , but i required spring boot mongo aggregation logic not mongo query .. mongo i know.

Answer (score 0):

```
@GetMapping("/group")
public List<ProductCount> groupByName() {

// grouping by prductName
  GroupOperation groupOperation = 
         Aggregation.group("productName").count().as("count");
// projection operation
 ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = 
 Aggregation.project("count").and("productName").previousOperation();      
// sorting in ascending
 SortOperation sortOperation = 
        Aggregation.sort(Sort.by(Sort.Direction.ASC, "count"));
// aggregating all 3 operations using newAggregation() function
 Aggregation aggregation = 
        Aggregation.newAggregation(groupOperation,projectionOperation 
        ,sortOperation);
// putting in a list 
// "products" is collection name
 AggregationResults<ProductCount> result =
        mongotemplate.aggregate(aggregation, "products", 
        ProductCount.class);    
 return result.getMappedResults();
    }
```

$ make ProductCount class in model package

```
public class ProductCount {
  private String productName;
  private int count;

  #getters
  #setters
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).