# MongoDB count (after grouping) using Aggregate gives Error: cmd.cursor is undefined

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get the count of entries that I have in the collection `collectionUID` grouped by the field `status` by using the commands suggested on https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116396/2806163

*Sample Response* in the collection:

> { "_id" : ObjectId("b....5"), "status" : "processing", "product_id" :
>   "a...2", "destination" : { }, ..., "request_id" : "b...d", "timestamp"
>   : "1536028784.0797083", "userID" : "Daksh" }

*Error*:**`TypeError: cmd.cursor is undefined`**

```
> db.collectionUID.aggregate([
...     {"$group" : {_id:"$status", count:{$sum:1}}}
... ])
2018-09-18T18:57:41.983+0530 E QUERY    [thread1] TypeError: cmd.cursor is undefined :
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1322:1
@(shell):1:1
>
```

PS:
mongo --version: **MongoDB shell version v3.4.10-4-g67ee356c6b**

Comment: Are you using mongoose or mongodb native direct?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet How do I find that out?

Comment: what is your mongodb native driver version?