# Mongodb dynamic $sum with condition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have documents similar to this in my mongodb

```
[

{
     key1:"6789",
     type:"A",
     points:2000    
},


{
     key1:"6789",
     type:"A",
     points:200000    
},

{
     key1:"777890",
     type:"A",
     points:10    
},
{
     key1:"777890",
     type:"A",
     points:1000    
}


]
```

I am looking to have the final sum based on `key1` and `type`, such that if two document have same key1 and type there points should be added

Final result something like

```
[
    {
     key1:"777890",
     type:"A",
     Sumpoints:1010

    }
{
 key1:"6789",
 type:"A",
 Sumpoints:2002000

}


]
```

Is this possible with mongodb ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB SELECT COUNT GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html) by more than one field specifying `_id` as an object:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { key1: "$key1", type: "$type" },
            Sumpoints: { $sum: "$points" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            Sumpoints: 1,
            key1: "$_id.key1",
            type: "$_id.type"
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JkANXbuKvFT)