# Group by and count MongoDB documents by a specific field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Could you please tell me how to group by and count the number of documents in MongoDB by the value of the user - name field in the following "tweets" collection?

Example of a key showing the desired field to group by and count:
[image: Desired field]

I'm currently using the following query:

```
db.tweets.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$name", total:{$sum:"$amount"}}}
])
```

and getting two empty columns:
[image: Two empty columns]

Please help me adapt the query to show the number of tweets (documents) per name (field).

Thank you.

Comment: This looks to be called `user.name`, not just `name`

Comment: And what is `amount`? For the count, you want `total: {$sum: 1}`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116396/14955

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. This query worked in this case: db.tweets.aggregate([
    {"$group" : {_id:"$user.name", count:{$sum:1}}}
])