# How to group by and count with MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am trying to group by and count with mongodb. Whatever I tried I couldn't do it.
This is my query

```
db.getCollection("requests").find(
    {
        "updatedAt" : {
            "$gt" : ISODate("2020-05-14")
        },
        "status" : "SUGGESTED"
    },
    {
        "user.email" : 1.0,
        "user.name" : 1.0,
        "updatedBy.displayName" : 1.0,
        "requestTerm" : 1.0
    }
)
```

I would like to group and count based on updatedBy.displayName

So result will be for me distinct displayname ( Column1), count ( number of times )

How can I achieve this?

This is what I tried and it seems it doesn't work

```
db.requests.aggregate(
    {$match: {         "updatedAt" : {
            "$gt" : ISODate("2020-05-14")
        },
        "status" : "SUGGESTED" }},
    {$group: {updatedBy: "$updatedBy.displayName", number: {$sum: 1}}}
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by , As stated over there you need to use `aggregate` with aggregation stages : `$match` for filter, `$group` for grouping & `$project` for projection.

Comment: Yes I checked but I couldn't put together. I added example of what I tried. @whoami

Comment: Please edit this question with sample docs & required o/p..

Comment: Here is an example of grouping and counting using aggregation: [$group examples](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/index.html#calculate-count-sum-and-average). In your code the `$group` stage requires `_id: <group by expression>`, _not the_ `updatedBy: ...`.

Comment: Your pipeline should be enclosed within square brackets `[{stage1}, {stage2}]` + `_id:"$updatedBy.displayName"`