# Mongo aggregate count by user

Tags: mongodb, aggregate

I have 3 tables

users
courses
types

a user has several courses and one course belongs to a type. how to return the number of courses per type per user?

Ex:

John

3 type A courses

5 type B courses

```
([
    {
        $match: {
            project_id  : ObjectId("5d9604074dc1e055a83520e9"),
            moderator_id : {$ne: null}
        }},
    {
        $lookup:
         {
           from: "pages",
           localField: "page_id",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "pages"
         }
    },
    {
        $lookup:
         {
           from: "users",
           localField: "moderator_id",
           foreignField: "_id",
           as: "users"
         }
    },
    {
        "$group" : {
            _id: { 
                moderator_id: "$moderator_id",
                type: "$pages.type",
                name: "$users.name"
            },
            root : {
                $first :'$$ROOT'
            },
            count:{$sum:1},
        }
    },
    {
        $sort:{
            "count":-1
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: a pergunta deve ser em inglês por favor!

Comment: de uma olhada aqui, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB SELECT COUNT GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by)