# mongoose select query with count from other collections

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregate

I am working with node(express) with mongoose and I have two collections,

1. Users
2. Comments

I added the sample Schema(added few fields only)

```
   const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      email: String,
    });
    
    const CommentsSchema = mongoose.Schema({
      comments: String,
      user_id: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User",
      },
      text: String,
    });
```

So I trying to fetch the users list and no of comments count based on user..

Expecting output like below:

```
data = [
  {
    name: 'abcd',
    email: 'aa@test.com',
    commentsCount: 5
  },
  {
    name: 'xxx',
    email: 'xx@test.com',
    commentsCount: 3
  }
]
```

I am not sure how to get the results, because we don;t have ref in user table..

```
userModel.find({}).exec((err, users) => {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
        return;
    }
    users.forEach(function(user){
      commentsModel.countDocuments({user_id: users._id}).exec((err, count) => {
       if(!err){
        user.commentsCount = count;
       }
    })
    });
    console.log('users', users)
});
```

Can you anyone please help to fix, I needs to list out the users and count of comments

[image]

Comment: A way to do this would be run a aggregate query on comments. Group on user_id and use count with `$sum:1`. You will have to map user_id back to get user details though.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23116396/8483196

Comment: I guess you would have to add a field `commentsCount` to your User Model

Comment: @KrzysztofPodmokły  the commentsCount fetch from other collections

Comment: @Ankit the link which you shared is the same collection(table) right? But i am expecting different collection(table) count.

Comment: Yes it's for same collection, but you will get the data which you want. After getting the aggregation result, query the user collection with the user_id to get the user details like name and email.

Comment: Other option is what Krzysztof suggested. In that case when ever a new comment is added, insert in comments collection and increase comments count of user in user collection.