# Mongodb : Group and sum by referenced field

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I'm trying to Group By a embedded document.

This is my document

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"610acbb68c1149ae85333753"},"numero_demande":"ERA-1624381087","client_datas":{"cotisation":"10000","qualite":["M."],"nom":"SABOM","prenom":"Manourou","email":"test@gmail.com","adresse":"Ouaga","prof":["366"],"activite":["700"],"date_effet":"2021-06-25T16:53:41.042Z","duree_contrat":"3","simulation_id":"60d2169fc31934a15cca1185","token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTYyNDM4MTIxOSwianRpIjoiNGNiMDIyY2QtY2YyYy00NzkxLTk1MTItMjk4YTA3MDQ3ZDgyIiwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInN1YiI6IjYwOTNlNDE2MzhmMDcxNTgzY2E0OTBjZiIsIm5iZiI6MTYyNDM4MTIxOSwiZXhwIjoxNjI0MzgxNTE5fQ.iI-Lz0Zh9FFiKBSusXsZaIkw9-kcFa5WcNcxiNSl0NZYnziHE2rOO0_-xIXEvaWbFIsaW2lY6iRczDY7jGOHTA"},"type":{"$oid":"60b4f154e077bf0f9da94376"},"user_id":{"$oid":"60d2169fc31934a15cca1183"},"status_id":{"$oid":"60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"},"result_simulation":{"montant_prime":330725},"selected_pack":{"montant_prime":330725},"date_created":{"$date":"2021-06-22T14:41:57.087Z"},"updated_date":{"$date":"2021-06-28T19:12:55.499Z"},"moyen_paiement":{"$oid":"610abe695c637c75446fa551"},"numero_police":"TEST01"}, {"_id":{"$oid":"610bfb41f76fcb2599219f17"},"numero_demande":"ERA-1628174841","client_datas":{"cotisation":"6800","valeur_verrerie":"","qualite":["M."],"nom":"hgvhgvgv","prenom":"jjjgjgjhg","email":"lkkjh@kjhkjhk.cjfk","adresse":"kjhgjhgjg","prof":["730"],"activite":["1055"],"date_effet":"2021-08-09T14:22:56.322Z","duree_contrat":"10","beneficiaires":[],"simulation_id":"610bf9f984467cd196219f10","token":"eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJmcmVzaCI6ZmFsc2UsImlhdCI6MTYyODE3NDg3MCwianRpIjoiZTYxNjI5M2EtNjU3NC00YWExLTlmOTYtYTQzYWNmNjA5ZTAzIiwidHlwZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInN1YiI6IjYwOTNlNDE2MzhmMDcxNTgzY2E0OTBjZiIsIm5iZiI6MTYyODE3NDg3MCwiZXhwIjoxNjI4MTc1MTcwfQ.upmeD6MgzacDai_2IelKPNBDb4dmbQteJpZYjomJ9H0Mb1B5CXW1LhI8iE5Sy7098bk0PKEVTvtOifq2KTz7YA"},"type":{"$oid":"60b4f154e077bf0f9da94376"},"user_id":{"$oid":"61033a6dfc10f6bf6383faa4"},"status_id":{"$oid":"60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"},"result_simulation":{"montant_prime":831277},"moyen_paiement":{"$oid":"610abe695c637c75446fa551"},"selected_pack":{"montant_prime":831277},"date_created":{"$date":"2021-08-05T13:36:06.353Z"},"updated_date":{"$date":"2021-08-27T11:25:36.183Z"},"numero_police":"TEST02"}]
```

status_id field is a reference on another document and this is how it look like :

```
[{"_id":{"$oid":"60b7cd6878817148201f98e3"},"libelle":"Devis généré"}, {"_id":{"$oid":"60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"},"libelle":"Saisie dans ORCYS"}]
```

And i want to group and count the first document by `status_id.libelle` and get something like this

```
[{
   libelle:"Saisie dans ORCYS",
   total: 1
},{
    libelle:"Devis généré",
    total: 0
}]
```

Comment: Can you explain more for "count the first document by `status_id.libelle`"? A [brief lookup and group count](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bycyKHK3QLP) returns 2 for Saisie dans ORCYS instead of 1 for your sample data.

Comment: And, it would be better that you shorten your sample data by only keeping relevant fields like `status_id`

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for. Thanks @ray

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB SELECT COUNT GROUP BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23116330/mongodb-select-count-group-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using a community member answer. The solution can be tested using this link:

https://mongoplayground.net/p/7xNYvHO-WAX

Considering this two objects:

```
db={
  "simulation": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "610acbb68c1149ae85333753"
      },
      "status_id": {
        "$oid": "60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"
      }
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "610bfb41f76fcb2599219f17"
      },
      "status_id": {
        "$oid": "60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60b7cd6878817148201f98e3"
      },
      "libelle": "Devis généré"
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"
      },
      "libelle": "Saisie dans ORCYS"
    }
  ]
}
```

If i want to have all `simulation` group and count by `status`, I should do this :

```
db.status.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "simulation",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "status_id",
      "as": "sourceLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 1,
      "libelle": 1,
      "total": {
        $size: "$sourceLookup"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

And the result will look like this :

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60b7cd6878817148201f98e3"),
    "libelle": "Devis généré",
    "total": 0
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60ba7de4c57cffaa5598811a"),
    "libelle": "Saisie dans ORCYS",
    "total": 2
  }
]
```

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.